# Can't go in recovery mode

Tags: boot, ssd, password-recovery, recovery-mode

Hi I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know a lot.
I have set my ssd storage as the boot device but the thing is
I want to go in recovery mode to change my password because I've forgotten it.

I have looked over some topics how to do it but every time my boot screen comes up it changes way too fast to press shift in time.

Is there some other (safe) way to go in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed something that works, for me at least. This is to restart again, when I reach the login screen. When I do so, this action appears the GRUB loader options, after the restart.

Not every time I restart I get the GRUB loader appearing, I am not aware of how this works. I use Lubuntu 14.04, a version of Ubuntu.